# plsql : Dynamic SQL inside Cursor

Tags: plsql, cursor, dynamic-sql

```
v_upd_cur := 'Select m.name, m.age'|| ' From ' || act_table || ' m Where m.age < 30';
```

This is the dynamic SQL select statement within a cursor. How do i put in the select statement inside a cursor named `cur`?

i tried something like code below which do not work, anyone has better suggestion?

```
Cursor cur IS v_upd_cur;
```

Answer (score 2):

your can try this using a sys_refcursor. Check the example below

```
DECLARE
    my_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_name      VARCHAR2 (100);
    v_string    VARCHAR2 (1000) := 'SELECT ename
                  FROM   emp';
BEGIN
    OPEN my_cursor FOR v_string;

    LOOP
        FETCH my_cursor INTO v_name;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_name);
        EXIT WHEN my_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE my_cursor;
END;
```

Comment: then how do i call the cursor? [For cur In v_name loop.....end loop;] , it can't work? @Dawn

Comment: you need to open the cursor and loop inside it

Answer (score 0):

You can open a static or dynamic refcursor the same way:

```
declare
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for select * from dual;
end;
```

```
declare
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for 'select * from dual';
end;
```

Then you just have to fetch it into a suitable record.

In 21c this is simplified somewhat. Let's say `employee_rectype` is a record type that matches the dynamic cursor of employees in `sql_text`:

```
for r employee_rectype in values of (
    execute immediate sql_text
)
loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r.firstname || ', ' || r.lastname);
end loop;
```